# Is there a NumPy C API function which will reset the layout flags?

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am manually modifying the shape and strides of NumPy arrays which may (or may not) invalidate the contiguity flags.

1. Do I have to then manually check whether the strides match the values you would expect from the shape and `NPY_C_CONTIGUOUS` (or `NPY_F_CONTIGUOUS`)?
2. Is there an API function which will do this for me and automatically clear or enable flags as is appropriate?

Comment: +1: Good question...I'd like to know to

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried these myself so I am not entirely clear on their use but you may try to employ:

1. `PyArray_CLEARFLAGS`
2. `PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS`

Found in the [Numpy v1.7 Array API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html)